# Random number generator seed in R

Tags: r, references, random-generation, reproducible-research

I have a question about the random number generator seed number in R.
Recently, I am trying to solve the exercises in the book named "An Introduction to Statistical Learning".
When I following the practices, I found pretty odd situation.
Although I set a same seed number, the result is slightly different from the book.

So, my question is that is it possible that a same seed number results in a different result?
I think, it could result from the version of my R
(or due to the fact that I am using R studio and the book employed GNU R)

Comment: Can you refer more precisely to the exercise. Which function or set of commands is generating a different answer?

Comment: Given my answer, were the differences of the same order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [the first page (first edition)](https://www.statlearning.com/) with `set.seed()` commands,

[image]

I was able to reproduce the outcome, using R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15). (R studio produces exactly the same.)

```
> set.seed(1303)
> rnorm(10)
[1] -1.1439763145  1.3421293656  2.1853904757  0.5363925179  0.0631929665
[6]  0.5022344825 -0.0004167247  0.5658198405 -0.5725226890 -1.1102250073
```

and

```
> set.seed(3)
> y=rnorm(100)
> mean(y)
[1] 0.01103557
> var(y)
[1] 0.7328675
> sqrt(var(y))
[1] 0.8560768
> sd(y)
[1] 0.8560768
```

the only difference being the excessive precision in my R output. Note the warning in the text about possible discrepancies occuring with new versions of R.

Comment: That's a good point. The OP's "slightly different" may simply be different output precisions. +1.

Answer (score 4):

The seed should make your analysis fully reproducible. I would much rather assume that differences in R (and package) versions, or a bug in your (or the book's) code, or possibly even machine/OS differences would be responsible for any discrepancies. (Converted from a comment.)